# TestID on flatlist not showing up when testing with react-native-testing-library

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, flatlist, react-native-testing-library

I am trying to unit-test my flatlist to make ure a view pops up once the flatlist has scrolled a certain amount of distance. My flatlist looks like this:

```
<FlatList
     testID={LIST_OF_TRANSACTIONS}
     ref={flatlistRef}
     bounces
     onScroll={scrollEventHandler}
     data={dateListOfTransactions}
     showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
     scrollEventThrottle={16}
     onContentSizeChange={handleContentSizeChange}
     contentContainerStyle={{
       paddingTop: maxHeaderHeight,
       paddingHorizontal: 30,
       paddingBottom: paddingToBeAdded,
     }}
     renderItem={renderItem}
   />
```

> LIST_OF_TRANSACTIONS = "LIST_OF_TRANSACTIONS"

I have written a test to be able to fire a scroll event and then check if the view is present or not as given below.

```
it("The scroll up button should be visible when the flatlist is scrolled", async () => {
const { getByTestId, queryByTestId } = render(<GetWrappedComponent />);
fireEvent.scroll(getByTestId(LIST_OF_TRANSACTIONS), {
  nativeEvent: {
    contentSize: { height: 600, width: 400 },
    contentOffset: { y: 200, x: 0 },
    layoutMeasurement: { height: 400, width: 600 },
  },
});
await waitFor(() => {
  getByTestId(SCROLL_UP_INDICATOR);
});
expect(getByTestId(SCROLL_UP_INDICATOR)).toBeOnTheScreen();
```

});

**GetWrappedComponent is just wrapping the component in a Provider for redux something like**

```
 <Provider store={store}>
  <TransactionList/>
</Provider>
```

The issue here is that I get the error like:

> Unable to find an element with testID: LIST_OF_TRANSACTIONS

Then it prints the tree and here I noticed that the individual renderItem views are getting some random testID as given below

```
<View
    testID="test-list-undefined"
  >
    <View>
      <Text>
        Mon, 3 Apr'23
      </Text>
      <View>
        <View>
          <View>
            <View>
              <View>
                <Text>
                  Withdrawn
                </Text>
              </View>
              <Text>
                4:02 pm
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text>
              <Text>
                +
                S$
                 
                <Text>
                  24
                </Text>
                .78
              </Text>
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
```

But there is not parent view with the testID that was passed to the Flatlist itself.
I thought that there would be a parent view of all the renderItem view with the testId as ***LIST_OF_TRANSACTIONS***. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you mocking FlatList or TransactionList?

Comment: await waitFor(() => {
  getByTestId(SCROLL_UP_INDICATOR);
}); I think this might be off, you can try `await expect(findByText(SCROLL_UP_INDICATOR)).toBeTruthy();` findBy has build in await functionality.

Comment: @VasylNahuliak Thanks for pointing that out. Indeed the flatlist was mocked and that was the cause of the issue. I updated the mock to suit my needs